# Redirect for unwanted GET params

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string

A search bot is scanning pages on my site with a lot of strange GET params right now. For example `?x?`, `?728%10%02`, `?%18%9B%D9%DF%05` etc. I don't know where the bot found that urls but it makes my cpu to smoke because a cache system doesn't process urls with GET params.

I have no ability to modify cache system, but i want to redirect requests with GET params to the same url without GET params through .htaccess. But I have some important GET params that shoudn't be redirected. It's `?s=...` for site search and utm labels.

In summary I want to redirect the following urls

```
/some-url?x?
/some-url?728%10%02
/some-url?%18%9B%D9%DF%05
```

and a lot of others GET params to

```
/some-url
```

But keep untouched urls like this:

```
/some-url?s=searh_term or
/some-url?utm_campaign=my_campaign
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've a selected number of GET parameters possible, then you can check against them in your htaccess file, and redirect all requests without the allowed parameters.

```
RewriteEngine On
# check that there is indeed a query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.+$
# check that it doesn't start with one of allowed parameters
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(utm_campaign|s|other|parameters|list)= [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [R=301,L]
```